# .click function showing alert but not decreasing the image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

i am using jquery in which i made a test function in which i set the size of image, i have 200 images in sharepoint list, i set the limit to show 100 at a time and call the function. first time when the page load it shows small size image which i set in my function, after i used .click event and i put the code in the document .ready and also call the function in it, it shows original size size image i want the image size should be set to 250px when i click the next button, when i click the next button it show me the alert both which is in the .click event and which is in the function, but image size does not change. so any one tell me where is the mistake in my code... here is my code.

```
<WebPartPages:ScriptEditorWebPart runat="server" Content="&lt;script   language=&quot;javascript&quot;type=&quot;
    text/javascript&quot;  src=&quot;http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js&quot;&gt; 
    &lt;/script&gt; &lt;script language=&quot;javascript&quot;     type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;

function test(){
    alert(&quot; we are here ! &quot;);

     var images = $(&quot;.ms-cellstyle&quot;).children(&quot;img&quot;).map(function(){

     $(this).css(&quot;width&quot;, &quot;250px&quot;);
}).get();
}


$(&quot;pagingWPQ2prev a&quot;).click(function(){
    alert(&quot; On click run..!&quot;);
test();
});

$(&quot;#pagingWPQ2next a&quot;).click(function(){
    alert(&quot; On click run..!&quot;);
test();
});



$(document).ready(function() {
    test(); 


});







&lt;/script&gt;" ChromeType="None" Description="Allows authors to insert HTML snippets or   scripts." Title="Script Editor" ID="g_971cb0df_9e1f_42a5_bf88_5e3fe4d57119"   __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{0795B887-2071-4083-AA7A-C164BF62540E}" WebPart="true"   __designer:IsClosed="false" partorder="4"></WebPartPages:ScriptEditorWebPart>
```

Comment: Im not going to read that code....

Comment: Please provide rendered code, not useless server side script or whatever it is

Comment: Have you tried setting the width to 250px!important?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by my self, but there is still a problem it have compatibility issue, it is working in FireFox only. can any one tell the reason???
 i have used this code, in the above code and it start working....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
test(); 
});


$(&quot;#pagingWPQ2next a&quot;).live(&quot;click&quot;,function(){
  alert(&quot; Outside On click run..!!!&quot;);
  test();
  alert(&quot;outside On click run..2!!!&quot;);

});

$(&quot;#pagingWPQ2prev a&quot;).live(&quot;click&quot;,function(){
  alert(&quot; Outside On click run..!!!&quot;);
  test();
  alert(&quot;outside On click run..2!!!&quot;);

});
```